# .NET doesn't read properly web.config?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config

I have

```
   <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="500000000"  />
    </system.web>
```

But when I read **web.config** via

```
 Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(configPath);

            HttpRuntimeSection section =
              (HttpRuntimeSection)config.GetSection("system.web/httpRuntime");
```

I see **4096** value for `maxRequestLength`!!

How it could be?? Thanks for any clue!

P.S. It is ASP .NET MVC3 Razor project

Comment: I had a similar issue that I never fully resolved, but some of the answers may be helpful in this case.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536550/wcf-service-reference-support-files-not-updating

Comment: _"Theoretically, the maximum file upload size is fairly large. However, because of ASP.NET health monitoring, you cannot upload very large files in ASP.NET. The ASP.NET worker process has a virtual address space of 2 gigabytes (GB). However, the ASP.NET worker process only uses a little more than 1 GB because of health monitoring and memory fragmentation. "_ http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295626/en-us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that 500,000,000 Kb is above the maximum value for the `maxRequestLength` property, so it's being assigned its default value (4,096). The documentation does not say what's the maximum value that `maxRequestLength` can take, but my guess is 20,97,151 Kb because that's roughly equal to 2^31 bytes, the maximum value that `int` can store.

Comment: OK. But I put any value ie 100000 and I can't see it anyway

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things to consider:

- Is your <system.web> element a direct child of the <configuration> element?
- Is your web.config file in the root of your IIS Application Scope root?
- Is the <httpRuntime> element locked in the "root" .config file so values can't be overridden by other config files?

If you're using IIS then I recommend using the Configuration editor to investigate configuration precedence.

Comment: Is your <system.web> element a direct child of the <configuration> element?  Yes

Comment: Is your web.config file in the root of your IIS Application Scope root? Yes